# How to access Control defined in Resource dictionary via code in .Net MAUI?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios, maui

This is my .net maui project ResourceDictionary. I have created ControlTemplate here to use it globally.

```
<ResourceDictionary 
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:ctrls="clr-namespace:Mobile.UI.Core.Controls;Mobile.UI.Core"
    x:Class="Mobile.UI.Core.Resources.CommonStyles">

 <!-- ControlTemplate -->
     <ControlTemplate x:Key="EntryFieldTemplate">
        <StackLayout
            ClassId="_entryFieldLayout"
            HorizontalOptions="{TemplateBinding Path=HorizontalOptions}"
            Orientation="Vertical"
            VerticalOptions="{TemplateBinding Path=VerticalOptions}"
            WidthRequest="{TemplateBinding Path=WidthRequest}">

            <Label
                x:Name="_entryFieldLabel"
                AutomationId="_entryFieldLabel"
                Style="{TemplateBinding Path=LabelTextStyle}"
                Text="{TemplateBinding Path=LabelText}" />

            <BoxView
                AutomationId="BoxViewPlaceholder"
                Style="{DynamicResource Key=LabeledFieldPlaceholderBoxViewStyle}" />

            <Entry
                x:Name="_entryFieldEntry"
                AutomationId="_entryFieldEntry"
                HeightRequest="25"
                Text="{TemplateBinding Path=Text, Mode=TwoWay}" />

        </StackLayout>
    </ControlTemplate>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

#### I want to access Entry control which have x:Name = "_entryFieldEntry" from custom control class using c# code.

I'm able to access ControlTemplate using this code:

```cs
var controlTemplate = Application.Current.Resources.TryGetValue("EntryFieldTemplate", 
out var controlTemplate);
```

We can not directly use `Resources.TryGetValue()` for Entry control because there is no `x:Key` property available to declare.

I want to access CollectionItems of ControlTemplate that I'm getting in collectionView.

I have did R&D  but not found any solution to access Entry control. I have tried to use FindByName() method but its not working.

Does anyone know how to do it? Any kind of help would be highly appreciated.

#### Update 05 May 2023:

I'm able to access ControlTemplate using code and I can see that controls I have taken is showing in that, but I'm not able to access it.

```
 var entryFieldTemplate = Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.
FirstOrDefault(rd => rd.ContainsKey("EntryFieldTemplate"));
 var template = (ControlTemplate)entryFieldTemplate["EntryFieldTemplate"];
 var collectionView = template.LoadTemplate.Target;
```

When trying to access node from collectionView I'm not getting any method for that. It shows only five options:

- Equals
- GetHasCode
- GetType
- LoadFromXaml<>
- ToString

[image]
[image]

Comment: you should use data binding to interact with templated controls

Comment: To define a data binding in c#, see second code snippet under [Bindings with a binding context](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/data-binding/basic-bindings?view=net-maui-7.0#bindings-with-a-binding-context): `label.SetBinding(Label.RotationProperty, "Value");`.

Comment: Do you mean to access the Entry control when it is Foucused or TextChanged?

Comment: No, means when page is loading at that time only all controls will get loaded at that time.

Comment: I'm getting all child controls in template but not able to access it, so want to know how I can access them?

Comment: You could refer to [Get a named element from a template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/controltemplate#get-a-named-element-from-a-template)

Answer (score 1):

After a control template has been instantiated, the template's OnApplyTemplate method is called. Then you could use **GetTemplateChild** method to get the named control.

```
protected override void OnApplyTemplate()
{
    base.OnApplyTemplate();
    var entry = this.GetTemplateChild("_entryFieldEntry");
}
```

For more info, you could refer to [Get a named element from a template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/controltemplate#get-a-named-element-from-a-template).